# console error when using jquery - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLElement> has no method

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I'm trying to add a class or a css style using the following js but getting a console error

```
var i = 0;

$(".question")[i].addClass("show");
```

get the following console log error: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'addClass'

or / and

```
$(".question")[i].css("display", "block");
```

get the following console log error: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'css'

used info from [http://api.jquery.com/get/](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get-index)

**EDIT**
Still doesn't working if get rid of the variable i, and use numbers 0 or 1

Comment: Can you show your markup?

Comment: $(".question").eq(i).addClass("show");

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you access an item from a collection with a subscript like `[i]`, you're actually unwrapping it from the jQuery object, and accessing a raw DOM node, which doesn't have methods like `addClass` and `css`.

Use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead:

```
var i = 0;
$(".question").eq(i).addClass("show");
$(".question").eq(i).css("display", "block");
```

Comment: Thank you very much @bfavaretto - been scratching the head for ages on this one!