# jquery giving TypeError getting elements from wrapped set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a rookie following an exercise to obtain the first element in the set of all img elements with an alt attribute. On p.35 of jQuery in Action 1st edition, I am entering the following commands in the "Wrapped Set Lab":

```
$("img[alt]").get(0)
```

or this:

```
$("img[alt]")[0]
```

both of these commands give this exception in the console:

**error:TypeError Object# has no method 'addClass'**

Here is the markup fragment:

```
<div>
  <img src="images/image.1.jpg" id="hibiscus" alt="Hibiscus"/>
  <img src="images/image.2.jpg" id="littleBear" title="A dog named Little Bear"/>
  <img src="images/image.3.jpg" id="verbena" alt="Verbena"/>
  <img src="images/image.4.jpg" id="cozmo" title="A puppy named Cozmo"/>
  <img src="images/image.5.jpg" id="tigerLily" alt="Tiger Lily"/>
  <img src="images/image.6.jpg" id="coffeePot"/>
</div>
```

[Yet another post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844023/console-error-when-using-jquery-uncaught-typeerror-object-htmlelement-has)suggested this is normal and wrote to use the following instead:

```
$("img[ALT]").eq(0)
```

which works and returns 1 element in the wrapped set:
    IMG#hibiscus

There is nothing in the errata section of the book for this. The responder to the SO post explains
"When you access an item from a collection with a subscript like [i], you're actually unwrapping it from the jQuery object, and accessing a raw DOM node, which doesn't have methods like addClass and css".

I am a rookie with jQuery and don't understand this error nor the explanation in a related SO post.

Answer (score 1):

`addClass` is a jQuery method. It can only be called on jQuery objects. When you call `[0]` or `.get(0)` on your jQuery object, you are fetching the underlying DOM element. That object doesn't support the jQuery methods.

You should call `addClass` on the jQuery object itself:

`img[alt].addClass('my-new-class');`.

If you only want to add a class to the first image with an `alt` attribute, you could change the jQuery selector to `$('img[alt]:first')`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like `$('img')` what you get is a jQuery object. This jQuery object contains 0 or more DOM elements (in this case, `img` elements). The `addClass` method is a method of a jQuery object. It assigns a class to every element contained in the object.

But when you do `$('img')[0]`, you are trying to retrieve the first DOM node contained in the jQuery object, if any. This node **is not a jQuery object** and so you can't use it to call methods from a jQuery object. You'd had to do something like

```
$('img').eq(0); //returns a new jQuery object with the element at position 0
```

or

```
$($('img')[0]);
```

which is basically another way of doing the same (jQuery can be constructed from a selector, another jQuery object, or native DOM elements.